# How to avoid image crop in BigPictureStyle notification

Tags: android, heads-up-notifications

[image]
[image]
I am using BigPictureStyle for showing image. But top and bottom part of the image is cropped. How can I avoid cropping image. Is there any other way to achieve this. Also I dont want to use custom views for that.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119593/android-notification-big-picture-dimensions, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189876/big-picture-is-cropping-while-setting-to-notification

Comment: @SamChen in these two stack question told about the dimensions and ratio of the image. But in my case I cant restrict dimensions or ratio. Whatever image given I need to show it

Comment: It seems like your goal is not that possible to be achieved at this moment, but my opinion is, the picture shown in notification is like a preview, then when user click it the complete picture shows up.